# Can't change the maximum request size (http error 413)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, server, asp.net-core-7.0

.net core 7 in development mode with vs 22, trying to get file of 50mb but getting http error 413.

I've tried a lot of different configuration but nothing seem to work.

examples:

setting.json:

```
"HttpRuntime": {
   "RequestSizeLimit": 524288000
}
"maxAllowedContentLength": 524288000
```

program.cs:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt => opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue);
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => {
     options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; 
});
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormOptions>(options => {
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
});
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => {
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
});
```

But nothing seem to work.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Above POST method you can have **RequestFormLimits** attribute. This attribute is needed for setting the maximum allowed file size.
Finally, on the Web.Config file set the maxAllowedContentLength as shown below.

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
```

Please read the following article for more knowledge. [Set MaxRequestLength in ASP.Net Core](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Set-MaxRequestLength-in-ASPNet-Core.aspx#:%7E:text=Increasing%20File%20Size%20Limit%20in%20ASP.Net%20Core&text=1.,maxAllowedContentLength%20setting%20in%20the%20Web.)

if this is not successful could you please add the following in the startup file or program.cs file? in the ***ConfigureServices*** method?

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

Comment: So in .net core 7 there is no web.config, u need to add it manually with the 
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
and then it's work.
There is no need for:
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
and no need for The  RequestFormLimits attribute - doen't seem to do anything. Maybe it's add another limit ontop of the web config - i didn't test 4 it.
Thx

Comment: @mudale  - I updated my answer. could you please try that one too?

Comment: i've tested the:
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
And it's not working without setting of the requestLimits in the web.config...

Answer (score 0):

We need to add `web.config` file with `maxAllowedContentLength` setting in asp.net core project. It can fix the issue.

I have test it in my local and it works well.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w5CV.png)

Both configurations of application level and machine level(add the web.config file manually) are necessary.

//
The size limit is configured within the file program.cs, you need to add the following settings:

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; 
        });
```

Please add the file web.config right under your root directory of your project, and add the following settings:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 1 GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If it is deployed on IIS,the Web.config is auto-generated,please also add the settings above.